# Как в генератор списка добавить условие?

Tags: python

пытался сделать так, но не работает

```
a = [int(input()) for i in range(5) if i % 10 == 0]
```

то есть нужно добавить условие, чтобы в список добавлялись только числа делящиеся на 10 без остатка

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: @Satseki неверный ответ выводит программа, добавляет все числа

Comment: В крайнем случае можете прочитать 5 чисел и потом профильтрировать

Comment: Как сделать за раз не знаю. По мотивам entithat можно так: `list(filter(lambda x: x % 10 == 0, (int(input()) for _ in range(5)))`

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы кто-то объяснил почему оно только одно значение читает.

Comment: В Вашем примере фильтруются индексы, а не числа. Под условие `i % 10 == 0` попадает только индекс 0, поэтому в список будет добавлено только первое введённое число.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разделите чтение и фильтрацию:

```
a = [i for i in (int(input()) for _ in range(5)) if i % 10 == 0]
#    ---------- ================================ --------------
#        ^          читаем пять целых чисел            ^
#        |                                             |
#        -----------------------------------------------
#                   отбираем кратные десяти
```

Тоже самое по частям:

```
# читаем пять целых чисел
# важное: мы их не читаем. Генератор ничего не читает пока его не попросят.
g = (int(input()) for _ in range(5))

# просим генератор прочитать числа и фильтруем их
a = [i for i in g if i % 10 == 0]
```

Comment: то есть `i for i in (int(input())` читаем числа, потом идет кол-во раз повторений и далее нужное условие, я правильно понял?

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Не очень наглядно, но за неимением отдельной синтаксической конструкции для связывания значения с переменной внутри генератора (вроде `let` в Haskell) можно использовать

```py
a = [
  x
  for _ in range(5)
  for x in [int(input())]
  if x % 10 == 0
]
```

Comment: Python 3.8+имеет оператор `:=`, который решает часть проблем подобного типа.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets с точки зрения семантики это не одно и то же. walrus operator - императивная конструкция, а let - функциональная.

Comment: ну переходим на SCALA )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets не обязательно переходить, можно ведь совмещать :) Я ничего не имею против императивного стиля и оператора `:=`, просто стараюсь избегать его в функциональном коде ([генератор списка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) - наследие функциональных языков)

Comment: Дружище, отредактируй немного свой ответ - добавь пустую строчку или что  - я заберу свой минус.  
А то пока не отредактировано  -  возможность изменить голос отсутствует.
.
Например  -  если не лень  - напиши как это выглядело бы на `Haskell`.
Сорри - погарячился

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ей богу, не стоит беспокоиться, от меня не убудет :) В ответ я это добавлять не буду, потому, что к вопросу отношения не имеет, но если интересно, в Haskell нельзя бесконтрольно создавать побочные эффекты, поэтому это будет выглядеть иначе: [так](https://ideone.com/WAn2GJ) или скорее [так](https://ideone.com/XZOAot).

Answer (score 4):

можно попробовать так, но это будет работать только на **Python 3.8+**

```
a = [n for i in range(5) if (n := int(input())) % 10 == 0]
```